# How can I read at most N bytes from a `Read` instance?

Tags: rust

I have a `Read` instance (in this case, a file). I want to read at most some number of bytes `N`, meaning that if the file has length greater than `N` I read exactly `N` bytes, but if the file length is less than `N`, I read to the end of the file.

I can't use `read_exact`, because that might return `UnexpectedEof`, which means I dont't know what size to truncate the buffer to. I also don't want to just use a single `read` call, since that is OS-dependent and may read less than `N`.

I tried writing this, using `Read::take`:

```rust
const N: usize = 4096;

// Pretend this is a 20 byte file
let bytes = vec![3; 20];    
let read = std::io::Cursor::new(&bytes);
    
let mut buf = vec![0; N];
let n = read.take(N as u64).read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
buf.truncate(n);

assert_eq!(buf, bytes);
```

I would expect `buf` to be equal to `bytes` after the `read_to_end` call, but the assertion fails because `buf` ends up being only zeroes. The buffer does end up being the correct length, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read_to_end()` expects a empty vector, you are providing it with one which is full with zeros. To fix your issue, rewrite your code using `Vec::with_capacity` which preallocates but does not fill the vector.

```rs
const N: usize = 4096;

let bytes = vec![3; 20];
let read = std::io::Cursor::new(&bytes);

// Use vec::with_capacity() to allocate without filling the vec
let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(N);
let n = read.take(N as u64).read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
buf.truncate(n);

assert_eq!(buf, bytes);
```

Comment: What happens is that it appends to `buf` and returns 20. Now `buf` is 40 bytes long, and you're truncating it to the first 20 zeroes.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`std::io::Read::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read):

```
use std::io::Read;
fn main() {
    const N: usize = 4096;

    // Pretend this is a 20 byte file
    let bytes = vec![3; 20];
    let mut read = std::io::Cursor::new(&bytes);

    let mut buf = vec![0; N];
    let n = read.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    buf.truncate (n);

    assert_eq!(buf, bytes);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e519ec7cd121f0db40625fc8cdb85546)

Note however that this may read less than even the full file size, although in practice this shouldn't be an issue for small files since file transfers are done in blocks, usually 4kB, and interruptions only happen on block boundaries, so any file smaller than a block should be read entirely.

Comment: This could under read. `read` doesn't guarantee it'll read `N` bytes.

Comment: @JohnKugelman note that the OP said that they want to read _at most_ `N` bytes, so under-reading is allowed by the question

Comment: I doubt that's what they want. I presume it's imprecise wording and they want "up to" `N` bytes. The fact that `read` can under-read ought to be mentioned in your answer, otherwise it's a hidden footgun (not only for the OP but for other readers who may want "up to").